# Do I need to percent-encode '=' when used as a query param value?

Tags: python, base64

[From Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html),

> base64.urlsafe_b64encode(s)
>
> Encode string s using the URL- and filesystem-safe alphabet, which
>   substitutes - instead of + and _ instead of / in the standard Base64
>   alphabet. The result can still contain =.

In short, python url-safe base64 does not seem to encode '='.

When my paramkey contains '=' (eg. "hello=world"), I have to urlencode it, else my param key will be interpreted as "hello" and value as "world=someval". Is there any scenario when I have to encode '=' in my param value?

Answer (score 0):

No, when base64-encoding data **all** byte values are encoded and the output won't contain literal `=` characters that are not a base64 character. It doesn't matter at all what ASCII values the input data has here.

You can easily test this:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode(b'=')
b'PQ=='
>>> base64.b64decode(base64.b64encode(b'='))
b'='
```

In the above, the `=` character stands for the `0x3D` byte value in hex (the ASCII codepoint for `=`), and that value is encoded as `PQ` (first 6 bits of `0x3D` is `001111`, so 15, which translates to the letter `P`, then the remaining `01` together with `0000` from a non-existing next byte makes 16 so `Q`), followed by two padding `=` characters.

Note that equals signs are really only used as padding. Many decoders tolerate missing padding at the end, and if not the padding is easily added back in.

URL-encoding on the other hand, only encodes **some** characters, not all; there are 40 characters that never need encoding (a-z, A-Z, digits and -, _, . and ~), while another 18 carry special meaning and thus need to be escaped. It is that mix of un-reserved and reserved characters that means you have to escape some characters if they don't have special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not talking about `=` in the input string (which gets base64-encoded as all the other characters), but about the `=` that can come up in the encoded string.

Now, `=` can only appear at the end of a base64-encoded string, and is completely useless (it's just used as a padding to reach a multiple of 4 characters). You can just trim it away and re-add it (if your base64 decoder is so picky about it) on the other end of the wire.